# Why does not "@Transactional(propagation = propagation.NEVER)" work?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-aop, spring-annotations

In the Spring docs, for `NEVER` propagation:

> Execute non-transactionally, throw an exception if a transaction
> exists.

I wanted to try like following:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
public void getDeps(long ID) {
    System.out.println(databaseImp.getDepartmentByID(ID));
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void allProcessOnDB_second(long ID) {
    getDeps(ID);
    operation(ID);
}

@Transactional
public void operation(long id){
    System.out.println(databaseImp.getDepartmentByID(id));
}
```

Well, it is not important what code wants to do.
I use the `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)` and I use this method in any *transactional* method but it doesn't work. I mean it must throw an exception, but it doesn't.

My Spring meta configuration file (XML) contains the following:

```
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan base-package="database.transactionmanagement"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="datasource2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="datasource2" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/hr"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@Transactional` annotations only apply to the Spring proxy objects. For example, if you call `allProcessOnDB_second()` from some spring bean which injects your service like this

```
@Autowired 
private MyService myService; 
...
myService.allProcessOnDB_second();
```

then `myService` is Spring proxy, and its `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` is applied. If you were to call `myService.getDeps(id)` then `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)` would be applied.

But when you call the first method, and then second method from it, then second method isn't called through Spring proxy but rather directly, so its transactional configuration is ignored.

Comment: yes @Predrag Maric, i try to do as you say, it works well, i have a question, Can we say that, if we use the Transactional annotation we need to use necessery proxy class and invoke the Transactional metod in this or these classes.

Comment: You just have to understand how it works, and then you can use it as intended. Most impotrant thing here is to understand the concept of Spring proxies.

Answer (score 6):

Spring transactions are proxy-based. That exception would be thrown if  a bean A called another bean B, because the transactional aspect would intercept the call and throw the exception. But here, you're calling another method in the same object, and the transactional proxy is thus out of the picture.